# Python 3: How Do I Stop A while-loop In class From Running After Every class I Added?

Tags: python, class, while-loop, break, python-3.5

I have a `while-loop` nested in a `Class "Function/Block"`. I did research and your are suppose to put `self.Counter (for example)`, if you want to put a counter in class. Before this I used a `break` function to stop my `while-loop`. It might be in the wrong place or it wasn't set up properly but, even though it's `False` it keeps continuing. Here is the code:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, Health, Attack, Defense):
        self.Health = Health
        self.Attack = Attack
        self.Defense = Defense
        self.Role = []
        self.Move = []
        self.RoleCount = 1
        while(self.RoleCount > 0):
            Input = input("What role do you want to be?\nChoices:\n1. Mage\n2. Warrior\n3. Archer\n4. Gunner\n")
            if(Input.lower() in ['mage', 'warrior', 'archer', 'gunner']):
                print("Your role is: %s" % (Input.upper()[0]+Input.lower()[1:]))
                self.Role.append(Input.upper()[0]+Input.lower()[1:])
                self.RoleCount -= 1
            else:
                print("That's not a role! Try again.")
Mage = Class(40, 20, 7)
Warrior = Class(60, 9, 10)
Archer = Class(50, 12, 18)
Gunner = Class(55, 16, 12)
```

You may need to run this so you can see the problem I am seeing but, whenever I run this, the `while-loop` keeps going even after it's `False`. If you can tell me why this is occurring and how to fix it I would appreciate it :). Thanks!

Also, here is the `break` version I tried before I tried the previous code. It still didn't stop the `while-loop`.

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, Health, Attack, Defense):
        self.Health = Health
        self.Attack = Attack
        self.Defense = Defense
        self.Role = []
        self.Move = []
        while(True):
            Input = input("What role do you want to be?\nChoices:\n1. Mage\n2. Warrior\n3. Archer\n4. Gunner\n")
            if(Input.lower() in ['mage', 'warrior', 'archer', 'gunner']):
                print("Your role is: %s" % (Input.upper()[0]+Input.lower()[1:]))
                self.Role.append(Input.upper()[0]+Input.lower()[1:])
                break
            else:
                print("That's not a role! Try again.")
Mage = Class(40, 20, 7)
Warrior = Class(60, 9, 10)
Archer = Class(50, 12, 18)
Gunner = Class(55, 16, 12)
```

I'm assuming the problem is the positioning of the `while-loop` but, I truly don't know. Any clarification would be helpful!

**Update Info 1: It keeps running for all of the "classes" I made but, I need those classes for verification of stats for each role i.e. 'Mage', 'Warrior', etc. How do I make the while loop run once even though their are four Classes?**

Classes:

```
Mage = Class(40, 20, 7)
Warrior = Class(60, 9, 10)
Archer = Class(50, 12, 18)
Gunner = Class(55, 16, 12)
```

Comment: Both snippets works fine. Learn more about providing [MCVE].

Comment: I just tried your non-break code and it is working fine for me. you are creating four objects that's why it is asking you for input four times. did you try creating just a single object ?

Comment: @Rogalski Both snippets, for me, keep running even after I answer `'Mage'` (For example). I'm doing this code on repl.it Python 3.

Comment: @sumit I want the user to pick one class out of the provided four.

Comment: This works fine for me in a repl using python 3.5

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It keeps asking the question but let me try again

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No it asks me the question four times

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you are creating four instances of the object? I don't know what else to tell you. I literally copied and pasted your class definition into a repl then did `mage = Class(40,20,7)` and it worked fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that's the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ? On what condition you want the while loop to stop ?. while observing your code, it looks like every time you call an object "Class", the RoleCount value updates to 1, and the last lime you call the object "Class", the RoleCount decrements and gets equal to 0, so your while loop ends.

Comment: ... Just don't create four objects. Delete the last three lines of your code.

Comment: Every time you create an instance of the class, it will ask the question.  Your create four instances and get four questions.  If it wasn't breaking out of the loop creating one class would ask questions forever.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need Those objects to verify the stats for each role.

Comment: @AnumSheraz But It keeps asking the qustion for every role I made why?

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's what I figured out.

Comment: Because you aren't making a new "role" when you say use `Mage = Class(40,20,7)`, you are making a new `Class`. It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding of OOP.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Really? I didn't know that. How do I fix that?

Comment: You should read about factory method. http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: No answer here but I think that 'Class' is a really poor name for a class since it is confusing with the class concept in OOP and has a great probability to be a reserved keyword in most OOP languages.

Comment: @TimF Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @DoronCohen Thanks for the input! I will read over it.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist It is going to ask the question the same amount of times that you create the object because you have the question within the class. I have provided a solution to your problem all you need to do is review it..

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I'm applying your answer. Hold on.

Comment: I've tested the code (the first one), it ask the question four times and then goes out of the while loop and code stops. (using python 2.7)

Comment: @AnumSheraz I only want it to run once though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the user to chose a class then I have adapted your code as follows!

```
class Role:
    def __init__(self, Health, Attack, Defense):
        self.Health = Health
        self.Attack = Attack
        self.Defense = Defense
        self.Move = []

def chooseClass():
    Roles = {
               'mage':lambda:Role(40, 20, 7),
               'warrior':lambda:Role(60, 9, 10),
               'archer':lambda:Role(50, 12, 18),
               'gunner':lambda:Role(55, 16, 12)
               }

    while(True):
        Input = input("What role do you want to be?\nChoices:\n1. Mage\n2. Warrior\n3. Archer\n4. Gunner\n")
        if(Input.lower() in Roles):
            print("Your role is: %s" % (Input.upper()[0]+Input.lower()[1:]))
            break
        else:
            print("That's not a role! Try again.")
chooseClass()
```

Comment: It wont run the while loop.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist Lol you have to call `choose_class()`... Updated code!

Comment: have you called the function "choose_class()" ?
if __name__ == '__main__':
   choose_class()

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__'` is unlikely to be required and will most likely only confuse the OP, best to keep it simple!

Comment: use `input.title()` instead of the ugly `input.upper()[0]+input.lower()[1:]`

Comment: and in python you should really consider using lowercase for your variables.

Comment: My goal was not to format his code, only to get it working.

Comment: and `.title()` will capitalize `[x[0] for x in string.split(' ')]` while `.capitalize()` will only capitalize `string[0]`

Answer (score 3):

It isn't an infinite while loop; everything works correctly. You're just calling the constructor four times, so it will prompt you four times.

It sounds like you want to do the following:

> Given some user input, if the input corresponds to a valid role, then return an instance of that role with various pre-defined stats. Otherwise, if the input is invalid, then loop until the input is valid.

In that case, we can do something like the following:

```
class Role:
    def __init__(self, health, attack, defense):
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.move = []

def choose_role():
    role_stats = {
        "mage": (40, 20, 7),
        "warrior": (60, 9, 10),
        "archer": (50, 12, 18),
        "gunner": (55, 16, 12)
    }
    menu = "\n".join([
        "What role do you want to be?",
        "Choices:",
        "1. Mage",
        "2. Warrior",
        "3. Archer",
        "4. Gunner",
        ""
    ])

    while True:
        choice = input(menu).lower()
        if choice in role_stats:
            stats = role_stats[choice]
            print("Your role is: %s" % choice.capitalize())
            return Role(*stats)
        else:
            print("That's not a role! Try again.")

role = choose_role()
print("Health: %d, Attack: %d, Defense: %d" %
      (role.health, role.attack, role.defense))
```

Comment: The only issue I see is that you are creating an additional 3 unused classes. In the long run it won't affect performance but if it can be avoided it is best to !

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Fair enough. I've modified my example to avoid this.

Comment: @Adriano Thank you for the stat input thing.